# Limit Size Of Objects While Uploading To Amazon S3 By Java

Tags: java, json, amazon-s3

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-bucket-springboot-microservice/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NumericLessThanEquals": {
                    "s3:content-length": "1024"
                }
            }
        }
    ] }
```

I tried to limit 1 file upload to S3 in Backend by limiting in policy settings but it is not valid
Is there any way to limit users to upload files larger than 10mb to reduce attacks by end users? I am currently writing code in Java.

I hope i can get some advice from some people to reslove this problem.

Comment: `if (file.length < 10MB) { upload to AWS }`

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc put where ?

Comment: There are no content length headers in the available [condition keys for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-policy-keys).  At best, you can have a Lambda check the size after the fact and remove objects that don't fit a criteria, or use a presigned post with a [content length range](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-PolicyConditions)